# drupal 7 views - access entire (!) views content after ajax refresh as json

Tags: ajax, views, 8

im facing the following situation:

i have a view with exposed filters. after the user has altered the view using the filters, i need to access the view's entire data as json. therefore its not enough to simply hook into the ajax call using drupal's ajaxComplete() function, since it would only return the html of the current page - whereas i need the entire filtered data.

how can i achieve that? i dont need a detailed solution, just a workflow to get me to the right direction.

thanks in advance, great community!

bg
thomas

**edit:**

for now ive solved it as follows:

i created a json display without pagination using the views_datasource module. in the ajaxComplete() function i make an ajax call to the json view's page with the serialized exposed fitlers form as get parameters et voila.

Comment: i wasnt yet allowed to answer to my own question and moreover id actually still like to get some input. i dont really like my solution cuz im using 2 views and it damn smells like there should be sth more efficient and clean.